How do I use react-hook-form and shadcn to set the value of an input field?
given a react component called "FormBlog" that is responsible to either update or create blogs based on the passed props, I want the prop values to be displayed in the input fields to facillitate user editing. I understand that shadcn has its own form field states that needs to be updated, so I cannot just add my own html value.
here is the code
"use client";
import React from "react";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { z } from "zod";
import { blog, MAX_LENGTH } from "@/schemas";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormLabel,
  FormMessage,
} from "@/components/form";
import { Button } from "./button";

const BlogForm = ({ title, length, content }: z.infer<typeof blog>) => {

  const [wordCount, setWordCount] = useState(content ? content.length : 0);

  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof blog>>({ resolver: zodResolver(blog) });
  
  const onSubmit = async (values: z.infer<typeof blog>) => {
    console.log(values);
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        className="border border-item-foreground bg-item p-7  rounded-2xl"
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      >
        <FormField
          control={form.control}
          name="content"
          render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem className=" my-5 min-w-[35%]">
              <div className="flex flex-col">
                <FormLabel className="text-[1rem] sm:text-[1.3rem] text-white ">
                  Content
                </FormLabel>
                <FormControl>
                  <textarea
                    placeholder="your blog here"
                    className="flex min-h-[200px] w-full rounded-md border border-item-foreground bg-transparent px-3 py-2 text-base shadow-sm placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-ring disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50 md:text-sm"
                    {...field}
                    //how do i set the value to content prop?
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      setWordCount(e.currentTarget.value.length);
                      field.onChange(e);
                    }}
                  />
                </FormControl>
                <span>
                  word count: {wordCount}/{MAX_LENGTH}
                </span>
                <FormMessage />
              </div>
            </FormItem>
          )}
        />

        <Button
          disabled={form.formState.isSubmitting ? true : false}
          type="submit"
          className="ml-auto mr-0 block"
        >
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default BlogForm;


when initializing the useForm hook all I needed to do was pass in the additional option called "defaultValues". This would set my form field values from the get go.
  const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof blog>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(blog),
    defaultValues: { title: title, length: length, content: content },
  });

